# Mongodb sink connector - Confluent hub

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have connected mongodb Kafka connector version 1.7.0 and integrated with Kafka with docker setup. I am using JAVA version 11. Here, I am getting two errors when I select the topic name it gives `An unexpected error occurred: java.lang.NullPointerException` error
even I tried to connect my mongdb by localhost declared in `connection.uri mongodb://localhost:27017`I got the error in ui window `Invalid connector configuration: There is one field that requires your attention` then its saying unable to connect the server.
why I am getting this error, Did I miss any configuration?
I have no replicasets in mongodb should i create replicasets?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running everything in Docker, then `localhost` is the Connect Server, not the Mongo database, and your Java version doesn't matter.

Assuming you are running Mongo in a container in Docker Compose, and the service is named `mongodb`, then you'd configure Connect with `mongodb://mongodb:27017`

More details about using Docker networking here - https://docs.docker.com/network/